# Android 10 ContentResolver access to MP3 files on flash drive

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore, android-contentresolver, lineageos

I have Android 10 (LineageOS) running on a Raspberry Pi 3. I have a USB flash drive connected to the Raspberry Pi with a load of MP3 files. I can see the drive and files using the "Files" app but even after clearing the Media Store cache and settings, I cannot list any of these files via ContentResolver.

With my Android 11 phone, it has an external SD card full of MP3 files and they are automatically part of the MediaStore database.

What can I do to get access to these MP3 files via ContentResolver/MediaStore?

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = this.getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

if (musicCursor == null) {
  Log.d(TAG, "scanAndAddViaMediaStore, null cursor!");
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "scanAndAddViaMediaStore, cursor count: " + musicCursor.getCount());
}
```

I get the below debug output:

```
scanAndAddViaMediaStore, cursor count: 0
```

I don't know if this is a coding issue on my part, a LineageOS specific issue/query or Android issue/query.

If this is related to scope storage, how can I grant permission to the MediaStore to access these MP3 files?

I have the following in my Android.manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I also tried VOLUME_EXTERNAL for the Uri but that hasn't helped either:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
  musicUri = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to acces them using the secodnd item returned by getExternalFilesDirs()?

Comment: Or to begin with: do you have andeoid:requestLegacyStorage="true" in application tag of maniferst file?

Comment: @blackapps yes I have that set to true. What parameter would I pass in to getExternalFilesDirs() as you suggest?

Comment: Just null will do

Comment: @blackapps It only returns my app folder with null - just the 1 entry in the array (a "files" folder to be exact)

Comment: Sorry, do not understand. It is ok that it returns the files folder. What is the problem? Its path will be something like `/storage/28EF-1DE5/Android/data/<packagename>/files`. Or not? And of the other (the first one mostly)  it will be  `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files`.  You got two items isn't it? Unclear what you got.

Comment: @blackapps it only returns the local files folder - the second one you mentioned. The MP3 files are in folders from the root of the USB drive. I don't understand how either of the URIs (paths) you refer to will give me access to that via ContentResolver and MediaStore.

Comment: You will not use mediastore then but File class.

Comment: @blackapps So Android 10 doesn't automatically go looking for media like Android 11 and earlier versions do by the sounds of things? Maybe I should just buy a Raspberry Pi 4 so I can run Android 11 on that also.

Comment: @blackapps I just don't know how I can use the File class. I'm not getting a folder returned. I may be able to use SAF but I'm scared the USB path will change upon re-insertion or reboot. Guess I'll just have to try. Raspi 4's seem to be like gold to get hold of at the moment.